# readdir only gives dots - php

Tags: php, opendir

So, I have this function and for some reason, it only returns dots, while anywhere else it returns what it should

```
function scan($dir){
    $open = opendir($dir);
    $Name = readdir($open);
    return $Name;
}

scan('/home/user/scan/scan-test2');
```

I used the exact same way of opening directories in another function
and for some reason there it reads everything that is inside `scan-test2`.

In `scan-test2` there is a folder with 4 text files in it

Comment: Why not use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: @IsThisJavascript scandir returns nothing or NULL with the warning " scandir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given"

Comment: It sounds like you're passing the result of `opendir` into `scandir` - you just need to provide the path. `readdir` only returns a single entry from a directory with each call, which is why this won't be working.

Comment: Your function only ever returns the first entry found in any case ... You need a _loop_ if you want all entries.

Comment: thank you all... didn't expect the answer to be that simple

Answer (score 0):

Use the [scandir()](http://php.net/scandir) PHP's function as this:

```
$files = scandir($path);
unset($files[0]); // remove .
unset($files[1]); // remove ..
```